# Connected fields in a SharePoint form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, form

I've been thrown into a complex situation in my workplace recently, I've never worked with SharePoint nor InfoPath, but we need to modify a form already in use in our website, we have a form in where when you select your name it automatically fill another field with your registration number.

What I need to do is to add more employees and their registration number, but I can't find where this two fields are connected, I am able to add their names to the list but not to "attach" more information to be auto-filled with it.

Comment: Hi @Fabricio_A. It's not clear about back-end data, if only "Name" entity comes from a SharePoint list or if "Name" and "Registration Number" are in SharePoint lists too or "Registration Number" comes from some Web Service (for example)? Please, if possible, it's important bring this detail.

Answer (score 0):

1.Edit list form in the InfoPath.

[image]

2.Add rule for the Name column.

[image]

[image]